# What does this binomial sum equal?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I'm trying to evaluate this sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}{{2n+1}\choose k}$$

I thought I could work with generating functions of the two binomials. I know
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k{}x^k=(1+x)^n$$
is the generating function for ${n \choose k}$ but I don't know how to find the one for $\binom{2n+1}{k}$ or if this would even be the correct way to evaluate this sum? Maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s

$$\sum_k\binom{n}k\binom{2n+1}k=\sum_k\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{2n+1}k=\binom{3n+1}n$$

by [Vandermonde’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Comment: @User: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+x)^n\cdot(x+1)^{2n}=(1+x)^{3n}$$

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}k x^{2n-k}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{3n}\binom{3n}k x^{3n-k}$$

Consider the coefficients of $x^{2n}$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}{{2n}\choose k}=\binom{3n}n$$

Comment: it's not $2n+1$ but $2n$ in the 2nd binomial

Comment: @GCab, Thanks for your observation